Trouble deploying docker containers with postgresql database, deployment on to AWS ECS stucks on provisioning
I have a simple architecture, where these 3 services have been dockerized: a client (react), a server (nodejs), postgresql database (using docker image). I have a docker compose file that builds the images and when ran locally, everything works as per usual.
The EC2 servers get created, however the public link is forever loading. The status of the task is stucked in "provisioning".
How do I solve this? Or suggest new ways to easily deploy my docker images online.
Thank you!
I have been trying to deploy it onto AWS by following these steps:

Push my images to ECR, where each image belongs in one repository
In ECS, I've created a task using solely EC2 configuration (with env variables and port mappings done), and created a cluster to run this task.


You need to check if the EC2 instance is joining the ECS cluster. There may be a networking configuration issue preventing that or something. Otherwise, there is way too little detail in your question for anyone to provide much help. I would point out that running a database like PostgreSQL on ECS is really a bad idea, and you should be using the AWS RDS service for that instead.
